# You dropped him like he's hot

Tags: meaning

> You dropped him like he's hot.

Could you explain this phrase in plainer language? 
(I understand 'he's hot' means, 'he's so cool'.)

Comment: Please give more context. What caused someone to say this?

Comment: I found it in the script of "Good Luck Charlie", a US TV-drama. That is in the dialogue between teenage girls; the one doesn't like the boyfriend of the other's and feels happy to hear the news of their break-up.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with idiomatic expressions is that they do not always attribute the same meaning to a similar wording.

When I say

> He's hot!

It can actually mean several things, depending on context, amongst which:

> He's very cool. (mind you, hot and cool here mean the same!)
>   He's sexually attractive.

If I were to say the same thing about a car, it could mean that the car is *stolen*!

Now, in the case of your example, *hot* actually means *hot*: *having a very high temperature*.

When you pick up an object that turns out to be very hot (high temperature), the normal reaction is to drop it very quickly (so as to avoid burning yourself).

Here, the actual figure of speech is in the *dropping him*, which means to end one's involvement with a person, end a relationship.

> You dropped him like he's hot.

Means

> You broke up with him incredibly quickly. (As quickly as you would drop a very hot object).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and polite answer. The phrases were followed like this; "You dropped him like he's hot,-even though he's not." Now I understand that the speaker mentioned two meanings of 'hot': one is 'incredibly quickly ' and the other 'cool guy'.

Comment: @user80513 - Interestingly, the "even though he's not" part refers to the fact that he is not _hot_ as in cool and attractive. The sentence uses different meanings of hot :)

Comment: Gotta love the anonymous downvotes :)

Comment: @user80513 if you had added that second phrase to your question it would have made everyone's task a little easier, instead of playing guessing games. Tsk, tsk, tsk! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a truncated version of the saying/idiom *dropped (sb/st) like a [hot potato](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drop+like+a+hot+potato).*

> to disassociate oneself with someone or something instantly.

Have you ever taken a baked (or microwaved) potato out of the oven without an oven mitt? It's *hot*, and you drop it onto a plate as quickly as possible. I remember a childhood game called "hot potato" where a child in a circle tossed an object at another random child who got rid of it as quickly as possible.

This writer (discussing the precipitous decline in Renren stock value) carries the metaphor even further:

> Renren's stock gets dropped like a hot potato infected with plague

Although someone may *be hot*, it doesn't mean that when he is discovered to be unemployed, with maxed out credit, and is due to go on trial for armed robbery, he wont be *dropped like a hot potato*.

Comment: My favorite "hot" idiom referred to the summer weather down in Tennessee. When it was sweltering, they would say it was "hotter than a two dollar pistol."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very interesting; "hotter than a two dollar pistol" sounds like those cheap pistols easily get too hot to keep in a hand. I can imagine the 'hotness' down there in Tennessee. Here in Japan, it is getting sweltering and humid, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an English saying of "too hot to handle." In that case, you would drop some-thing or -one because they are "hot."

It could even be "too much of a good thing." You may meet and find someone who is sexy, attractive or whatever, that is "hot," until you realize that the person "hot"--to everyone else.